# Fill an array recursively walking a DOM tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have to fill an array of strings as I walk a generic tree recursively from one node to all his children. In practice at each node that match from a node to a leaf, insert a string in the DOM tree.
I know it is a trivial problem but I could not solve.
This is the code that I wrote:

```
function operationsToInsert(node) {
   var operations = [];
   operationsToInsertRec(node, operations);
   return operations;
}

function operationsToInsertRec(node, operations) {
   var childNodes = node.childNodes;
   operations.push("i(" + node.nodeName + ") ");
   for(var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
      operationsToInsertRec(childNodes[i], operations);
      operations.push("i(" + childNodes[i].nodeName + ")");
   }   
}
```

But there is the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined** at line `operations.push("insert(" + node.nodeName + ") ");`

How can I fix?
Thanks

Comment: In the first line of your for loop, you don't retrieve the value returned by operationsToInsert.

Comment: @James Could you explain better? I did not understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to walk a tree using the handy Array.prototype.reduce function using a trick that lets it work on array-likes:

```
function flatten(ops, n) {
    ops.push("i(" + n.nodeName + ") ");
    if (n.childNodes && n.childNodes.length) {
       [].reduce.call(n.childNodes, flatten, ops);
    }
    return ops;
}

var node = document.getElementById("start_here");
var ops = [node].reduce(flatten, []);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mc9czx42/)

Comment: Thanks, I modified my code in this way `function operationsToInsert(node) {
   var operations = [node].reduce(operationsToInsertRec, []);
   return operations;
}

function operationsToInsertRec(node, operations) {
   operations.push("i(" + node.nodeName + ")");
   if(node.childNodes && node.childNodes.length) {
      [].reduce.call(node.childNodes, operationsToInsertRec, operations);
   }
   return operations;
}` but I had the error **Uncaught TypeError: operations.push is not a function**

Comment: You have the parameters the wrong way round.  The `operationsToInsertRec` function needs to accept `(operations, node)` , not `(node, operations)`.

Comment: Thanks, and if I wanted to get an array as above but filled with nodes that are traversed in order bottom-up? Like that `[b, a, d, c, node]` or `[d, c, b, a, node]`

Comment: You could replace "reduce" with "reduceRight" to traverse the tree from the bottom up - should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have only one function, and it isn't what you think it is!  You redefined it, so when you call what you thought was the first one you provided only one argument, and the remaining arguments are implicitly `undefined`.

Here is your same code, reduced to a demonstratable example:

```
function operationsToInsert(node) {
   console.log("Definition #1");
}

function operationsToInsert(node, operations) {
    console.log("Definintion #2");
}

operationsToInsert();
```

You need to change the name of one of your functions so that you don't have a collision.

---

---

*Edit to address new question:*

I think you are saying that your new issue is most nodes appear in the list twice.  Trace through the code and you'll see that you process every node except the root node twice.  In `operationsToInsertRec()` you put the node in the list (`childNodes[i]`), then you pass it to `operationsToInsertRec()` where it puts it in the list (`node`).

Here is a simple change to address that:

```
function operationsToInsert(node) {
   var operations = [];
   operations.push("i(" + node.nodeName + ") ");
   operationsToInsertRec(node, operations);
   return operations;
}

function operationsToInsertRec(node, operations) {
   var childNodes = node.childNodes;
   for(var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
      operationsToInsertRec(childNodes[i], operations);
      operations.push("i(" + childNodes[i].nodeName + ")");
   }   
}
```

In `operationsToInsert()` I push the root node.  Then `operationsToInsertRec()` only handles the children, and so handles each node only once.

In a comment on a different answer I see you touch on the topic of traversal order.  When traversing a tree, there are several different classifications of these algorithms:  *depth-first*, which is subdivided into *pre-order*, *in-order*, and *post-order*, and *breadth-first*.  You can find more information in the wikipedia article on [tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was a problem and now (by renaming the second method) is no more error. However, the method does not do what it should. The array that returns has more elements than it should (that is, equal in number to the size, ie the number of all its children + himself)..

Comment: is wrong to traverse a tree because the internal nodes are visited several times then the method adds more strings concerning these nodes, while there should be a string for each node